# Measure of an angle "subtended by each pentagon" in a truncated icosahedron

Tags: solution-verification, solid-geometry

A soccer ball is a truncated icosahedron; it consists of 12 black regular pentagons and 20 white regular hexagons; the edge lengths of the pentagons and hexagons are congruent. What is the measure of the solid angle (in ste-radian) subtended by each pentagon of the soccer ball?

**My Explanation:**

If the edge length of the regular pentagon is $a$, according to mathworld.wolfram.com, the radius of the circle circumscribing the pentagon is
\begin{equation*}
R = \left(\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{50 + 10\sqrt{5}}\right)a \approx 0.8507 a ,
\end{equation*}
and the radius of the circle inscribed in the pentagon is
\begin{equation*}
r = \left(\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt{5}}\right)a \approx 0.6882 a.
\end{equation*}
So, the length of the line segment between a vertex of a pentagon and the midpoint of the side of the same pentagon across from this vertex is
\begin{equation*}
R + r
= \left(\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{50 + 10\sqrt{5}}\right)a + \left(\frac{1}{10}\sqrt{25 + 10\sqrt{5}}\right)a
\approx 1.5388 a.
\end{equation*}

According to wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron, the radius of the sphere circumscribing the truncated icosahedron is 
\begin{equation*}
\frac{a}{4} \sqrt{58 + 18\sqrt{5}} \approx 2.478 a.
\end{equation*}

An implementation of Heron's Formula yields the distance between the center of the sphere and the midpoint of a side of the pentagon of about $2.427a$. An implementation of the Law of Cosines shows that the angle with its vertex at the center of the icosahedron and its endpoints at a vertex of a pentagon and the midpoint of the side of the same pentagon across from this vertex is approximately $36.5^\circ$.

**Is that correct? Is that what is meant by "the angle subtended by each pentagon"?**

Comment: I think it is the solid angle.

Comment: What is the area of one of these pentagons projected onto the sphere?

Comment: Look for pyramid in https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle

Comment: @N74 That is for a square-based pyramid. This is a pentagon.

Comment: There's also the case for regular n-gon. Please read the whole paragraph

Comment: @N74 This is what I have.

Comment: According to math.wikia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_pyramid, the altitude of each pyramid with a regular pentagonal base of edge length $a$ is ...

Comment: ... $h = a\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}}$.

Comment: The radius of the circumscribing sphere is $r = \frac{a}{4}\sqrt{58 + 18\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{1 + \frac{r^2}{h^2}} = \sqrt{1 + \frac{1}{8} \cdot \frac{58\sqrt{5} + 90}{\sqrt{5} - 1}} \approx 4.81838$.

Comment: According to the website you suggested, the solid angle is $2\pi - 2\cdot 5 \arctan{\frac{\tan(\pi/5)}{\sqrt{1 + r^2/h^2}}} \approx 4.7866$.

Comment: @N74  Does that look right?

Comment: I'm too busy to review your steps, but I suggest you to take all these comments and arrange them in a self answer, so that it can be properly reviewed (by anyone).

Comment: Boundaries of the six sides of the hexagons should be geodesics, i.e., part of great circles, right? better to mention in the question.

Comment: Solid angle in *steradians* is $\dfrac{A}{R^2}$ where $A$ is area of any patch on sphere of radius $R$.

Comment: Pentagon edges can be chosen either geodesic or non-geodesic right?

Comment: @user74973 : I've just posted an answer which uses the websites provided by N74. I hope that my answer could help.

Answer (score 3):

[The wikipedia about solid angle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle) says that

> The solid angle of a right $n$-gonal pyramid, where the pyramid base is a regular $n$-sided polygon of circumradius $r$, with a pyramid height $h$ is
>   $$2\pi -2n\arctan\bigg(\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})}{\sqrt{1+r^2/h^2}}\bigg)$$

Note here that our $r$ is the circumradius of the pentagon (not the radius of the sphere circumscribing the soccer ball). So, according to [the wikipedia about regular pentagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#Regular_pentagons), we get
$$r=a\sqrt{\frac{2}{5-\sqrt 5}}=a\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{10}}$$

Now, considering a right triangle $OAB$ where $O$ is the center of the soccer ball, $A$ is the center of the pentagon and $B$ is a vertex of the pentagon, we get
$$\small h=OA=\sqrt{OB^2-AB^2}=\sqrt{\bigg(\frac{a}{4}\sqrt{58+18\sqrt 5}\bigg)^2-\bigg(a\sqrt{\frac{5+\sqrt 5}{10}}\bigg)^2}=a\sqrt{\frac{41+25\sqrt 5}{8\sqrt 5}}$$

So, the solid angle we seek is
$$2\pi -10\arctan\bigg(\frac{\tan(\frac{\pi}{5})}{\sqrt{1+r^2/h^2}}\bigg)\approx 0.29507$$

Comment: Oh, thanks for taking the time to look at my work. I had assumed that the "r" in one of the websites was the radius of the sphere circumscribing the icosahedron. You stated that the "r" is referring to the radius of the circle circumscribing each of the twelve regular pentagons. It does say on the website that "The solid angle of a right n-gonal pyramid, where the pyramid base is a regular n-sided polygon of circumradius $r$, with a pyramid height $h$, is ...

Comment: ... $2\pi - 2n\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(\pi/n)}{\sqrt{1 + r^2/h^2}}\right)$."

Comment: Augghhh! Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

We know that the normal distance $H_p$ of each of 12 regular pentagonal faces from the center of a truncated icosahedron with edge length $a$ is given by following [formula](https://www.academia.edu/9844328/Mathematical_analysis_of_truncated_icosahedron_and_identical_football_Applications_of_HCRs_Theory_of_Polygon_and_HCRs_formula_for_platonic_solids_)
$$H_p=\frac{a(2\sqrt5+1)}{\sqrt{10-2\sqrt5}}=\frac{a}{4}\sqrt{\frac{250+82\sqrt5}{5}}$$

The solid angle subtended by any regular polygonal plane with each side $a$ at any point lying on the perpendicular at a distance $h$ from the center is given by generalized formula from [HCR's Theory of Polygon](https://www.academia.edu/8747694/HCRs_Theory_of_Polygon_solid_angle_subtended_by_any_polygonal_plane_at_any_point_in_the_space_) as follows

$$\omega=2\pi-2n\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2h\sin\frac{\pi}{n}}{4h^2+a^2\cot^2\frac{\pi}{n}}\right)$$

Now, substituting the corresponding values $h=H_p=\frac{a}{4}\sqrt{\frac{250+82\sqrt5}{5}}$ and $n=5$ in above formula, the solid angle subtended by each regular pentagon $\omega_p$ at the center of truncated icosahedron (soccer ball) is

$$\omega_p=2\pi-2\cdot 5\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{2\frac{a}{4}\sqrt{\frac{250+82\sqrt5}{5}}\sin\frac{\pi}{5}}{4\left(\frac{a}{4}\sqrt{\frac{250+82\sqrt5}{5}}\right)^2+a^2\cot^2\frac{\pi}{n}}\right)$$
After simplifying, one will get
$$\boxed{\color{red}{\omega_p}=\color{blue}{2\pi-10\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{9-\sqrt5}{12}\right)\approx 0.295072263}\ sr}$$

Answer (score 0):

Based on the website provided by N74, I am posting the calculations that can obtain the answer to the question in my post. I would appreciate the efforts of someone knowledgeable in solid geometry to peruse my calculations and tell me whether it is right.

I got an answer of about 4.7866. If the solid angle of the whole sphere is $4\pi$, this answer is too big, considering that there are 12 black regular pentagons on a soccer ball.

**My calculations**

I am looking to calculate the measure of the solid angle subtended by each pentagon of a soccer ball.

$a$ denotes the edge length of each regular pentagon. According to

```
math.wikia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_pyramid,
```

the altitude of each pyramid with a regular pentagonal base is
$$h = a\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{1}{5}}} \approx 0.52573 a.$$
According to

```
wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_icosahedron,
```

the radius of the sphere circumscribing the truncated icosahedron - the soccer ball - is
$$r = \frac{a}{4}\sqrt{58 + 18\sqrt{5}} \approx 2.478 a.$$
According to

```
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle,
```

the measure of the solid angle subtended by each pentagon is
$$2\pi - 2(5)\arctan\sqrt{\frac{\tan(\pi/5)}{\sqrt{1 + r^2/h^2}}}.$$
As
$$\sqrt{1 + r^2/h^2} \approx 4.818358,$$
the measure of the solid angle subtended by each pentagon is approximately 4.7866.

Answer (score 0):

In the following required quantities are defined and arrived at by direct calculation using only the Sine/Cosine Laws in spherical trigonometry.

Areas of a spherical triangle $ = ( A+B+C-\pi)\; R^2 $ is dimensioned spherical excess. The spherical excess in turn is nothing but the solid angle$ =  A+B+C-\pi. $  The three concepts of area, spherical excess and solid angle are bound together. The solid angle has also been called Integral Curvature by Gauss.

Examples: For a full sphere of area  $4 \pi R^2$  a solid angle $4 \pi$. A spherical triangle with three right angles has solid angle $\pi/2$ like an octant of a sphere. A hemisphere can be considered to be enclosed by a spherical triangle with 3 vertices $120^{\circ}$ apart on equator, so spherical excess is $ 3 \pi -\pi= 2 \pi. $

In what follows it is assumed that all pentagon/ hexagon boundary lines of the soccer ball (formed by spherical icosahedron truncation) are part of great circles..i.e., the center of the soccer ball, P and Q lie in an equatorial plane. Euclidean length of the icosahedron edge is 1. A correction is applied for circular arc. We consider the corner spherical triangle $OPQ$ of the icosahedron shown magnified in the hand sketch below to base calculations.

[image: FootBall & Sketch]

The side of central curvilinear hexagon is $h$. It is required to calculate $h, \beta$ before Area of pentagon and Solid angle are calculated.

Arc length $s$ of the curved icosahedral side is slightly larger than edge length $1$;

$$ s= 2 R_{sph}\sin^{-1}({1}/{2 R_{sph}})\tag1 $$

Law of Cosines supplies an implicit relation to for numerical evaluation:

$$ \cos h = \cos ^2 [(s-h)/2] + \sin ^2 [(s-h)/2] \cos 2 \pi/5 \tag2$$

Law of Sines to find $ \beta $

$$ \dfrac{\sin [(s-h)/2]}{\sin \beta}= \dfrac{\sin h}{\sin 2\pi/5} \tag3 $$

Area of a spherical triangle (non-dimensionalized) by definition/formula is its spherical excess.. $ 5 \times \Delta OPQ :$

$$ \text{Area}= 5( \;2 \pi/5 + 2 \beta-\pi)= 10 \beta - 3\pi \tag4$$

Definition of solid angle is the non-dimensionalized Area.

$$ \text{Solid Angle}=\dfrac{\text{Area}\; on \;\text{Sphere}}{R_{sph}^2} \tag5 $$

Analytical expressions with surds etc. avoided in numerical work, can be inserted if it is felt that it would simplify.

Numerical results respectively approx.

$$( R_{sph},s, h,\beta, \text{Surface Area, Solid} \;\text{Angle} )$$

$$=(0.951057,1.05296,0.386778,0.969114,0.266365,0.294486) \tag6 $$

Solid Angle $= 0.294486 $ steradians subtended at sphere center by the convex pentagon.

Comment: I appreciate the careful explanation. I am not familiar with solid geometry. You had stated that if $A$ is the area of the pentagon and $R$ is the radius of the sphere circumscribing the truncated icosahedron - the soccer ball, the solid angle in steradians is $A/R^2$. So, the solid angle of the soccer ball is $4\pi$.

Comment: I was told that 0.265 is not the measure of the solid angle (in steradians) subtended by each pentagon at the center of the soccer ball, though.

Comment: @user74973 I was looking for your comments to see if we are on same page.

Comment: I appreciate the careful calculations and the diagrams!

Comment: As I am not familiar with solid geometry, I am not sure why your answer is not right - at least why I was told that $0.265118$ is not right. I am also not sure how the calculations that I performed using the websites provided by `N74` do not lead to the same answer.

Comment: @user74973 Trying to understand how to get a proportion of the solid angle in your ( N74 ) answer. There are twelve pentagons in your reply amounting to total 12*4.7866= 57.4392 staradians whereas maximum solid angle available on a ball is $4 \pi = 12.5664 $ staradians. How could that be possible?

Comment: I know that the answer I got is wrong. I admitted that in my post. I am saying that my calculations are based on formulas furnished by three reputable websites. How am I not getting the correct answer - or the same answer as you got?

Comment: To my frustration, the mistake I made was not correctly interpreting the $r$ from the Wikipedia entry on "solid angle." I had interpreted it as the radius of the sphere circumscribing the icosahedron. That is a mistake. It is the radius of the circle circumscribing each of the twelve regular pentagons.

Comment: Yes. effort wasted, but not your fault, happens. deleted all the EDIT1.

Comment: As I know nothing about solid geometry, I was just trying to blindly use the formulas in the websites furnished by N74 to get the answer. These websites have always been reliable. So, when I wasn't getting the right answer, and I thought that I was following the directions, I decided to put a bounty on it. Maybe an edit was needed on Wikipedia.

Comment: Wikipedia was just fine.

Comment: I wasted my time, and I wasted your time. My apologies.

Comment: No,no..not your fault at all as I already told.You did the best thing that was open to you.

Comment: @user74973: Actually difference between mathlove and mine is not much. Not even  one upvote for my basic approach..